# Mavericks calendar events longer than 3 hours

Tags: macos, calendar

I am using Mavericks.

I use Calendar in monthly mode and with times in 24 hour mode.

When I enter or edit an event in Calendar.app it seems to be limited to 3 hours.
First you have to deselect the whole day then the list of end times only goes to 3 hours, which I can live with. But if I close the drop down and try to edit the end time end time directly as if I put in a later time Calendar changes it to 3 hours. However only sometimes (about 50% success)

How do I enter an entry longer than 3 hours?

Comment: seems like a bug. I can easily make a event longer than 3 hours. Can you drag a event longer than 3 hours?

Comment: Are you looking to customize the drop down to have other value intervals? I've never had problems entering long events so perhaps I'm not understanding your issue well enough?

Comment: I could not enter the time to a time longer than 3 hrs - using the method in Felix_Sim's answer - but this seems to work now. So there was some other factor when I did this

Comment: Oh wow - now that might be a challenge to track down.

Comment: Does the symptom occur when logged in as a different or new user, or on a different Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the issue.

The method which is what I tried is as per Felix Sim's and mwd27's answers.

The issue seems to be that there is a timer on the time field to type say 18 you have to hit the 1 and then 8 close enough together and my typing is just slow enough to sometimes hit the timeout and Calendar puts the old value back.

GutierrezDev's answer works for me reliably as it only requires one key press.

Answer (score 4):

I use the + quick event button which is the same as Command-N to enter:

```
meeting from 10am to 5pm on thursday
```

It makes blocking specific times quite easy using Calendar app. I also often use the week or day view and create a default event and drag the bottom of the event to the end time.

Lastly, I select the hour when I mouse to raise the quick interval drop down and rather than use the mouse to change the end time, just type the hour and tab to the minutes field if necessary.

Comment: The first part is probably the best way and I will try to use that - however the last paragragh should work but does not always

Answer (score 1):

One way that might work is the following:

1. Click on the `Event "To" Time`.
2. When the drop-down menu appears, press `Esc`.
3. Double-click on the hours/minutes of the "To" time. It should be highlighted now (orange for me).
4. **Then press** `Arrow Up`.

Slightly inconvenient but hopefully it solves the issue.

Comment: As noted this sometimes works :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Create a new event
- Click on the end time hours
- When the drop-down menu appears type in the end time manually, e.g. "23"
- Hit return or click outside the bubble to enter the new event

This worked for me successfully on Calendar 7.0 (1835.1).

Comment: This is they way it should work but I can get out as per my question where the number can't be typed in

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't so much attempt to provide a complete answer, but rather an explanation of what's (probably) going on and why some of the others' answers are good workarounds.

The quick explanation is that this appears to be a poor logic/design decision for instant enforcement of data integrity rules at the expense of natural, easy data entry. In short, if you need to change the "to" time from AM to PM (or vice versa), you likely need to make the change to AM/PM first, *then* change the hour & minute (which could easily explain why you may only see it about 50% of the time).

**Workaround Roundup**

- As bmike suggests, using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for quick event entry is perhaps the easiest solution, or at least the most consistently easiest. (You never even  have to think about whether you'll have to change AM/PM).
- Felix_Sim's solution of using the arrow keys to change the hour also works, because that will automatically change AM/PM as the hour changes from 11 to 12. This should work well, though could easily be less efficient with numerous events with durations of several hours.
- If you don't mind switching to 24-Hour Time (System Preferences > Language and Region), then mwd27's solution will work, because there is no AM/PM switch to get in the way.
- Finally, you could also make sure you change AM/PM first, then go back to the hour. It's not elegant, but it will work.

I would also strongly recommend [sending feedback to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) requesting time not be validated until *after* it has been completely entered, rather than while it is actively being entered.

**Explanation, Observations & History**

The problem appears to occur in Mountain Lion and Mavericks under these conditions:

1. The automatically entered "to" and "from" times are both "AM" or both "PM", and
2. The user attempts to change the "to" time to a time that will require:

   - toggling AM/PM, *and*
   - the new hour is a number less than the hour in the "from" time, *and*
   - the hour is entered *before* AM/PM is changed.

The problem appears to be the result of how Calendar ensures that the "to" time is later than the "from" time (to avoid a negative duration).

In Lion and earlier, Calendar (or iCal, at that time) would check that the "to" time was later than "from" after the user finished entering *all* date & time fields (it was actually a single field with multiple parts in that version, rather than separate fields). If an earlier time was entered, it would revert to the previous valid time. In Mountain Lion and Mavericks, Calendar makes this check *as* each individual field is being entered, making it impossible to change the hour in "to" to a smaller number than "from" until AM/PM is changed.

**Example:** Say you have an event, "from 9:00 AM to 10:00 AM" and want to change it to "from 9:00 AM to 3:00 PM". The expected way to enter the "to" time is to enter "3" for the hour, then change "AM" to "PM". Here's what happens:

- **Lion:** The user can type "3" in the "to" hour then change "AM" to "PM" then exit the date & time field.
- **ML & Mavericks:** The user can type "3" in the "to" hour, but, because "AM" hasn"t been changed yet, the resulting "to" time would be 3:00 AM, which is not valid because that"s before 9:00 AM, so it is rounded to the nearest possible valid time (rather than reverting to the last valid time that was entered), which is 9:00 AM.

Comment: Unfortunately I am in 24 hour mode and have these issues but many of the points in here seem correct (as in the UK I did not think to point out I was in 24 hr mode as it is the only sensible way)

Answer (score -1):

After you put the end time from the list (3 hours Max) then use Arrow up to add more hours.

Comment: This seems to work at all times - the others sometimes stop